# ttk and quitter modules in python

Tags: python

I'm learning Tkinter using online tutorials (like http://zetcode.com/gui/tkinter/layout/ ) and others. I have python 2.6.6 on Slackware 13.37.

When I try to import ttk or quitter I get error messages telling me there is no such module. Here's what I've done:

from Tkinter import Tk, W, E
from ttk import Frame, Button, Label, Style
from ttk import Entry

or

from quitter import Quitter

Can anyone tell me what's going on? I've looked at the other questions on this site concerning this question and none of them have helped me.

I can't find a ttk or quitter module online, or any site that has any info that solves my problem.

Programming Python 2nd edition has examples with quitter that don't work. What I'm trying to do is to have a popup window that will allow users to input some info and have the box go away when the info is entered.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use ttk from Python, you need a separate install you can get from [here](http://code.google.com/p/python-ttk/). Also threre is no quitter modyle in the standard library <s>(not sure where you can get it)</s>.

EDIT: Quitter module seems to be from a book "Programming Python, 3rd Edition". [Here's](http://www.gidforums.com/t-12698.html) the quitter source code.

Comment: Thanks root. I have PP 2nd edition and quitter isn't listed in the index, nor could I find it with a 15min peruse. I also searched online and didn't see the page you found with the code. Thanks. Do people doing gui in python these days use Tkinter? I'm getting the idea that they don't.